# What does "arrange all variables to range over one domain" mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In these [notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf) (page 18, section 1.3.7)

> **1.3.7 Variables Over One Domain**
>
> When all the variables in a formula are understood to take values from
> the same nonempty set, $D$, it’s conventional to omit mention of $D$. For
> example, instead of $\forall x \in D \ \exists y \in D.\ Q(x, y)$ ***(1)*** we’d write $\forall x \exists y.\ Q(x, y)$ ***(2)***. The unnamed nonempty set that $x$ and $y$ range over is called the *domain of discourse*, or just plain *domain*, of the formula.
>
> It’s easy to **arrange for all the variables to range over one domain**. For example, Goldbach’s Conjecture could be expressed with all variables ranging
> over the domain $\mathbb{N}$ as
>
> $$\forall n.(n \in Evens) \implies (\exists p\ \exists q. p \in Primes \land q \in Primes \land n = p + q).$$

Now I have two questions

1. It doesn't make sense to me that ***(2)*** is the same thing as ***(1)***. Omitting the name of the set makes me think that ***(2)*** is actually more general, so what are reasons that I shouldn't think that?
2. Could you please explain the second paragraph in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can approach FOL from a "pure" syntactical way, where :

> $\exists x \forall y Q(x,y)$

has **no** "built-in" reference to the *domain* of the interpretation.

The same formula can be interpreted in different domain, with diofferent "meaning".

Consider for example the binary predicate $\le$ as interpretation for the predicate symbol $Q$.

Now the above formula is :

> $\exists x \forall y (x \le y)$.

We can interpret it in the *domain* $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers, and we have that :

> $\mathbb N \vDash \exists x \forall y (x \le y)$

i.e. the formula is satisfied in it, because we have taht the number $0$ is "less-or-equal" than any natural number $n$.

If instead we interpret it in $\mathbb Q$, the same formula is not satisfied any more, i.e. :

> $\mathbb Q \nvDash \exists x \forall y (x \le y)$

because there is **no** *rational* number which is less-or-equal than any rational number $q$.

__

Regarding the "formalization" of Goldbach’s Conjecture, we can omit **all** the reference to domain and subdomains, simply introducing suitable predicates :

> $∀n[(Even(n) \land n > 2) \to ∃p ∃q(Prime(p) ∧ Prime(q) ∧ n=p+q)]$.

Now all variables "range over" the same domain;  Goldbach’s Conjecture is the assertion that the above formula holds in $\mathbb N$, i.e. that :

> $\mathbb N \vDash ∀n[(Even(n) \land n > 2) \to ∃p ∃q(Prime(p) ∧ Prime(q) ∧ n=p+q)]$.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're pedantic, you'd say that **(2)** just doesn't  make sense really because from my understanding mathematics is based on a proper treatment of sets and logical quantors. Beginning to omit them for the sake of saving a few symbols isn't worth the confusion you risk by doing so. In that sense **(2)** is just a notation/convention where you say "if it is clear from the context that we're working on a set $D$, then we might omit it in **(1)** as well and just write **(2)**".
2. The second paragraph basically follows the idea (instead of explaining it in detail I'll make an example to illustrate it): If you have sets $D_1$ and $D_2$ and maybe a statement like
   $$
   \exists x\in D_1 \ \forall y\in D_2: Q(x,y)
   $$
   then you can simply define $D := D_1 \cup D_2$ as the union of these two sets and rewrite the above expression as
   $$
   \exists x \in D: \left( x \in D_1 \wedge \forall y\in D: \left(y\in D_2 \Rightarrow Q(x,y)\right) \right),
   $$
   which by the above notation is the same as
   $$
   \exists x: \left( x \in D_1 \wedge \forall y: \left(y\in D_2 \Rightarrow Q(x,y)\right) \right).
   $$
   And you can do just the same with the Goldbach conjecture.
   If you do not immediately see why these expressions are the same, it is perfectly okay $-$ it's just unnecessarily complicated to rewrite it this way.